# Связать списки между собой

Tags: c#, mvvm

Есть два класса, предоставляющие данные со свойствами: 1) Класс People: ID, Name, ProductID; 2) Класс Product: ID, Name.

ProductID в Классе People - внешний ключ для ID классак Product.
   В проекте на WPF, есть два ListBox, у первого ItemSorce забиндин на список People, а второй ListBox, на некий список, который обновляется при выделении элемента в первом ListBox(вызывается команда которая передает параметр выделенного People по ID выбирает Procuct который нужно отобразить).

Собственно проблема в том, что если добавить элемент в список Product, то в ListBox, который содержит пробукт не произойдет автоматического обновления, так как биндинг осуществляется не на оригинальный список а на список выборки, что бы это список уже обновился нужно изменить выбор элемента в списке а потом повторно быбрать что бы отработала команда. Как сделать, что-бы происходило автоматическое обновление? Только исходя из MVVM, так как если не учитывать MVVM, то проблем с этим бы не было.

Comment: Не очень понял проблему. Что если вызвать руками обновление нужного списка в нужный момент?

RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyList);

Comment: Вы используете EF? Приведите, если не сложно, код, иллюстрирующий проблему, а то из одного описания непонятно. (Ну и объясните, где у вас VM, а где модель.)

Comment: Пока ждал, додумался вручную обновлять список, сделал так же как советовал wind.